# sbt Docker publishLocal fails on apk

Tags: docker, sbt

Running `Docker/publishLocal` in sbt on Windows11, trying to create a Docker image of a project. Command fails almost at end, like so:

```
[error] #16 2.053 /bin/sh: 1: /sbin/apk: not found
[error] #16 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /sbin/apk add --no-cache bash bind-tools busybox-extras curl strace]: exit code: 127
[error] ------
[error]  > [mainstage 6/6] RUN /sbin/apk add --no-cache bash bind-tools busybox-extras curl strace:
[error] ------
[error] executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /sbin/apk add --no-cache bash bind-tools busybox-extras curl strace]: exit code: 127
```

UPDATE: I believe this is caused by the instructions to create the Docker image that are present in `build.sbt`:

```
Cmd("RUN", "/sbin/apk", "add", "--no-cache", "bash", "bind-tools", "busybox-extras", "curl", "strace")
```

My WSL2 uses Ubuntu, so it does not have `apk`. I have replaced "apk add" with `"apt-get", "install"`, but now I get this new error:

```
[error] #16 1.752 E: Unable to locate package bind-tools
[error] #16 1.752 E: Unable to locate package busybox-extras
[error] #16 1.752 E: Unable to locate package strace
[error] #16 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install bash bind-tools busybox-extras curl strace]: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Are you sure you have used he correct tag `apk`?  The one you have used is about Android apps.

Comment: @Robert I am not sure about anything. I am a beginner, and I am trying to make this example work on my machine https://github.com/akka/akka-sample-cluster-kubernetes-dns-java/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: I was talking about Stackoverflow - and some one with ~4K reputation is not a beginner...